# Has any planet accepted into the United Federation of Planets left after technology was shared?

Tags: star-trek, federation

Apparently, all versions of the Federation Charter seen in-canon and in various semi-canon texts strongly imply that technology sharing takes place as soon as a planet becomes a member of the Federation. Has any planet resigned membership from the Federation after this technology transfer occurred? The Federation seem pretty thorough in their application process (several planets have been denied) but has any planet ever 'scammed' the Federation to get advanced tech by joining and then left after the transfer?

Comment: As far as I remember, no planets have left the Federation in the canon up to now, but in the EU there may be some examples.

Comment: @Rebel-Scum - I can confirm that there is at least one example in the EU: the planet Yuukei, led by the Emperor Baaress J'nsn.

Comment: I'm not sure we have many examples of new Federation members to know how quickly they get access to technology. We do know that the Vulcans were slow with helping Earth, actually making them discover a whole lot on their own, and I've always assumed that model was copied. In other words, do you have evidence of this widespread sharing early on, when severing ties would be easy?

Comment: @Rebel-Scum the Federation has ceded planets to other states. See the Marquis for example.

Comment: The Maquis were Federation citizens who left the Federation due to their disagreement about the treaty with the Cardassians, they didn't scam the Federation to give them technology and then left. Totally different things ;-)

Comment: Why would you ever *leave*? If getting the technology without giving anything back is what you want, why not just take the technology without giving anything back? Whatever federation constraint or regulatory framework you don’t like, just ignore it. Stress the rules as much you like, until *they throw you out*. Since that is a formal process that takes time, you’ll continue enjoying the benefits without sacrificing anything until the process is completed. So why would you ever formally declare “*I quit, stop giving me the benefits of the membership right now*”? Instead, Brexit that federation

Comment: @Rebel-Scum the treaty in which their planets were ceded to Cardassia.

Comment: With all the episodes talking about Prime Directive and First Contact, I got the distinct impression that "transforming a culture overnight with technology" was something they learned a hard lesson about.  It would seem that for many reasons both practical and social a technology update to a planet would take decades to be carried through to the end.  In regards to technology, to build things you need some knowledge, engineering schematics, and the proper industrial base.  The first two are easily stolen; the latter is hard to come by.  A high-tech industrial base must be developed over time.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In canon, no planet has ever scammed the UFP in that way because, as you pointed out, the application process is very thorough and lengthy. The UFP can spend years or decades thoroughly reviewing a planet's application for membership to ensure that the application is honest and that the planet does conform to the guiding principles of the UFP's Constitution.

The only known canon example of a planet who willingly broke off from the UFP is Turkana IV, an Earth colony and place of birth of the late Lieutenant Natasha Yar. As far as we can infer, it had nothing to do with having gained technology from the UFP.

For reasons that were never stated on screen, the planet began to experience unrest in the 2330's. The government was apparently unable to do anything to remedy the situation and finally handed much of the power to the two major factions at the time, the Alliance and the Coalition, as its final act before it broke down completely. The planet severed its ties with the Federation in 2352 and was still in a state of civil war when the Enterprise visited in 2367. Its status afterwards is unknown.

Comment: I think it is compelling to note this planet is a colony.  Perhaps the OP intended to ask about a "species" or "homeworld" having joined and then left.  Yet the answer is correct -- this is the only canon example of a planet leaving.  Although I am pretty certain "planets" join the Federation, and while "planet" and "species" are certainly intertwined, they aren't equivalent.

Comment: I did note that it is an Earth colony in my answer. I don't recall if the distinction between 'planets' and 'species' has ever been addressed when it comes to Federation membership in the shows. The RPG books address the issue by stating that only the homeworld of a species becomes a member, their colonies remain under the purview of the central government and do not gain membership as well, since that would give way too much power to expansionist species, like the Humans, who colonized many planets.